# How to override the model's update method in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class model which has some fields and I have put up unique constraints on some of those fields.
Now my query is I am updating some of my classes status to cancelled, that led me to the error.

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique-class"
DETAIL:  Key (class_id, calendar_date, is_cancelled, cancellation_count)=(6-9Hip523, 2021-10-27, t, 0)
```

I want to skip this error on model level. How to do that?
My custom update method is not getting called, please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

my model

```
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['class_id', 'calendar_date', 'is_cancelled', 'cancellation_count'],
                                    name='unique-class')
        ]


    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_cancelled:
            try:
                super().update(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                print("Classes are already cancelled.")
```

Comment: This is not the update of the model, but of the `QuerySet`. What you can do is override the `clean` method and raise a validation error. If you then use a `ModelForm`, `ModelAdmin`, or `ModelSerializer`, it will show the corresponding error.

Comment: yes I am updating these objects through a queryset. but I want to do that for this case only. I can update my classes from anywhere from my code. So do I have update each models get_queryset method?

Comment: I would advise to override the `clean` method, or the `validate_unique` method, then raise a validation error. If you work with `ModelForm`s/`ModelAdmin`s/`ModelSerializer`s, then normally this will show the errors in the response. Django's models do not validate themselves for performance reasons. You can, if you do this in a view, wrap it in a `try:`-`except:` block.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to override the clean method, I have looked up the django docs but I couldn't; get to understand on how to use it. My doubt lies in how will I check that when I will call an update through a queryset. It shouldn't; save those classes and it also should not throw the unique constraints error.

Comment: you should wrap it into a `try`-`except` clause in that case.

Comment: i have to do that at every place where I am doing an update for my classes?

Comment: if you are doing this with `MyModel.objects.filter(...).update(...)` *yes* (as said, Django does not validate because that would be a performance bottleneck), if you update (mutliple) object(s) through a `ModelForm`, `ModelFormSet`, `ModelSerializer` or `ModelAdmin`, then you can implement validation logic in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`.update(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) is  is not provided by the model, but by the `QuerySet`. While you can strictly speaking override that, I would advise *not* to do this.

What you can do is override the [**`clean()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) or [**`.validate_unique(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) and raise a validation error. If you then use a `ModelForm`, `ModelAdmin`, or `ModelSerializer`, it will show the corresponding error.

We thus can implement this in the model with:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModel(models.Model):

    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = MyModel.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(
            class_id=self.class_id,
            calendar_date=self.calendar_date,
            is_cancelled=self.is_cancelled,
            cancellation_count=self.cancellation_count
        ).exists()
        if qs:
            raise ValidationError('Classes are already cancelled')
        return super().validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        # …
        pass
```

If you update it through the Django ORM, then it will not perform validation. In that case you can try to update the object, and catch the exception, so:

```
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError

try:
    MyModel.objects.filter(…).update(…)
except IntegrityError:
    # …
    # do something
    pass
```